# "It was my op" what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

I heard this in [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1229238) movie.
`It was my op.`
What does it mean?
Googling gave me : 'Original Poster'.
But that doesn't seem very meaningful.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/op#Noun Do not google. Use a dictionary. That is precisely what dictionaries are there for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***"Op"*** is short for *operation* - in the context of your link, most likely of a military nature. The character was basically saying *"It was my operation (mission)."*

Definition from M-W online:

> 6 a : a usually military action, mission, or maneuver including its
>   planning and execution

Comment: @MD.MohiuddinAhmed Just to be clear, ***op*** can be - and very often is - used to refer to a **surgical** operation (at least in British usage). So please don't think that ***op*** *usually* refers to a military operation (although I'm not disputing that that is the most likely usage in the quoted context).

Comment: @TrevorD, thanks anyway but the OP didn't ask about the definition of the word "operation" which would be off-topic for EL&U and really general reference. :-)