# Does OP mean “original poster” or “original post”?

Tags: meaning, terminology, abbreviations, expression-choice, initialisms

In an online forum, OP means "original poster," but can it also mean "original post?"

For example, instead of saying

> To answer the OP's original question...

could one instead say

> To answer the question in the OP...

or would this be an improper use of the term?

Comment: I'm uncertain in what way this was marked as a duplicate of [“It was my op” what does it mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116198/it-was-my-op-what-does-it-mean). As far as I can tell, they're two completely separate questions.

Comment: The answer in the the marked "duplicate" deals with op as short for operation, and not actually a dupe. However, I am not sure if this question belongs here or in meta. Vote for reopen.

Comment: Since this is a perennial question both at EL&U and across the Web, I think it is useful for the question to be asked and answered on this site. It is not related (as far as I can tell) to the claimed duplicate "['It was my op' what does it mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116198/it-was-my-op-what-does-it-mean)" that was originally cited as grounds for closing it.

Comment: In most cases you can tell from the context whether "original poster" or "original post" is intended.

Comment: Oh wow, the older question had nothing in common with this question, except for two letters "op" which is a shortening of "operation" not an initialism.

Comment: In my opinion, you should refrain from using "OP" or other ambiguous abbreviations. At least on StackExchange, use "question" and "questioner" respectively.

Comment: @IllidanS4, that's often even more ambiguous, because it might refer to a question that someone asked in the comments rather than the parent question.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that unless the OP (i.e. @Vyren) decides to ‘unaccept’ an answer, the user who posted their question, cannot delete it by themself. Scott has supplied a poor answer, with no references or support. It also completely fails to mention that OP stands for `Original Poster` *and* `Original Post` This means that users are downvoting and upvoting the best answer to show just how wrong Stensland's answer is.

Comment: But for some reason they are upvoting the OP, the question is not, in my view, particularly worthy. I hope when Vyren returns online they will uncheck the green mark, but in the meantime, I'm casting my vote to delete the accepted answer.

Comment: The original poster is "Opie".

Comment: Related/cross-site duplicate on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146513/241919)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

People all over the Internet have asked the same thing—which, on the face of it, suggests that different forum posters (and perhaps, in some cases, the same people at different times) have used it to mean both things.

For example:

> [Does OP mean Original Post or Original Poster or both?](https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/does-op-mean-original-post-or-original-poster-or-both.1493103/) (AnandTech, posted January 7, 2005)
>
> [Does OP mean the original post or poster?](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/does-op-mean-the-original-post-or-poster.207101/) (Physics Forums, posted January 3, 2008)
>
> [Does OP stand for "Opening Post," or "Opening Poster?"](http://www.kongregate.com/forums/2-on-topic/topics/166167-does-op-stand-for-opening-post-or-opening-poster) (Kongregate, posted May 7, 2011)
>
> [What does OP mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean) (Meta Stack Exchange, posted September 10, 2012)
>
> [Noob Question: What does OP mean?](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/6572267711) (World of Warcraft Forums, posted September 15, 2012)
>
> [what does op mean?](http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=990016) (League of Legends Forum, posted January 3, 2013)
>
> [OP -- Original Post or Original Poster?](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=813608) (The Straight Dope, posted December 12, 2016)

If you examine these various discussions, you'll see that, typically, someone will say that *OP* stands for *original poster*, and then someone else will say that it stands for *original post*, and then someone else will say that it can be used to mean either thing, and then someone else will suggest that it stands for something off the wall like *Otto Preminger* or *Opossum Party*.

At English Language & Usage, I think, most longtime participants use *OP* as an abbreviation of *original poster*, but not everyone follows this convention all the time.

Perhaps the most neutral, descriptivist handling of the abbreviation that I've come across is the one in Daniel Chandler & ‎Rod Munday, [*A Dictionary of Social Media*](https://books.google.com/books?id=UlExDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT176&lpg=PT176&dq=OP+%22original+poster%22+%22original+post%22&source=bl&ots=QBclF7L1_F&sig=wAxbqyDD5lqOjVSkssR1jgxuAec&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqiub22LLYAhXlr1QKHbddDfc4ChDoAQhbMBA#v=onepage&q=OP%20%22original%20poster%22%20%22original%20post%22&f=false) (Oxford, 2016):

> **op** 1. **(OP)** In online forums, short for *original poster* (who started a thread) or *original post* (the message that started it).

Comment: Yes, this abbreviation is very fluid. I've even seen it used to mean ***O**ther Post(er)*, for any upstream post(er) in a thread. Typical usage would be something like "As one of the OP's said..." Similar to PP, for previous post(er)—in some cases it may even be a typo for PP, but I'm pretty sure it's often an intentional usage.

Comment: In other words, the meaning of OP should be determined from context. If the context is ambiguous (both senses fit) so be it.

Comment: @1006a certainly on Slashdot (which had a role in popularising the use) PP for parent post(er) and GPP for grandparent post(er) are both used, and OP carries both meanings.

Comment: Pretty certain that in World of Warcraft context (outside the forums), OP almost always means "overpowered", carrying the implied suggestion that Blizzard should probably [nerf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerfing_(gaming)) the thing that is OP. The link to the WoW forum post in this answer actually confirms that.

Answer (score 19):

I'm not really sure who is qualified to say that one use or another of this abbreviation is "correct" or "incorrect". But I have certainly used "OP" to stand for "original post" instead of "original poster". The [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/op) entry for "OP" gives this as a possible meaning:

> (in online forums or comment pages) original post (or poster).

It also gives the following relevant example sentence:

- > ‘Oops, upon closer inspection of the OP, I see you weren't looking for a "blame" song.’

Answer (score 12):

Either ***or*** an abstraction related to both, depending on context.

To be clear, **"*OP*"** may refer to:

- the **O**riginal **P**ost; or
- the **O**riginal **P**oster; or
- the **O**riginal **P**ost *or* the **O**riginal **P**oster, ambiguously;
- the **O**riginal **P**ost *and* the **O**riginal **P**oster, abstractly.

When it's ambiguous, the writer may be thinking of the post or the poster.  They may fail to specify which for a variety of reasons, ranging from believing that the definition normally refers to the one that they intend to simply not caring to specify.

However, others mean **"*OP*"** abstractly as "*the original source of the content*".  They're not actually referring to either the post or the poster specifically, so we can't say that their usage of **"*OP*"** maps to one over the other.

The distinction between this abstraction and ambiguity is the presence-or-absence of [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency).  For example, **"*laugh out loud*"** may be the etymology of **"*LOL"***, but **"*LOL*"** isn't an acronym for it, such that substituting one for the other would change the meaning of a text.

Likewise, **"*OP*"** may have an ambiguous etymology and often refer to either the post or the poster in some cases, but there's also a separate definition distinct from these.  It'd be most precise to say that this separate definition is distinct from either of its etymologies, much like **"*LOL*"** is distinct from **"*laugh out loud*"**.